# chrome webstore: what are the possible ways to publish older version of the extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have published a private extension to Chrome webstore. Only people with URL can download this extension.

Some of the users in my organization want to switch to the older version of the extension for sometime. what is the best way to do?

- I am aware that chrome webstore doesn't support multiple versions on the same URL.
- Sending .crx file is not an option (due to the bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=638725)

I was thinking to publish the older version of the plugin (with different ID) to the store and give them the new link to download. Does the webstore allow?

are there other ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking to publish the older version of the plugin (with different ID) to the store and give them the new link to download. Does the webstore allow this?

Yes, there should be no problem, especially for the same developer account. It's not atypical to have a "stable" and "testing" versions of the same extension in the Store.

Consider making a mechanism to migrate user settings before you do this (for example, using [External Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external) between the two versions or some sort of copy-paste export/import).